# How to put two WHERE conditions in SQLite select statement?

Tags: sql, sqlite

My question is in a SELECT statement that fetch `SQlite` databse.

Assume I have the following `Table1`: ref_no, name, start_date

Assume also I have `Table2`: ref_no, payment

I want to select `table2.ref_no`, `table2.payment`, `table1.start_date` and `table1.name` where `table2.payment` is null and where `table2.ref_no` equal `table1.ref_no` sorted by `table2.ref_no`

I've tried this:

```
SELECT ref_no.Table1, name.Table2, tel.Table2
FROM Table1, Table2
WHERE payment.Table1 IS NULL OR
      payment.Table1 = ' 
ORDER BY ref_no.Table2
WHERE table1.ref_no = table2.ref_no
```

but no success ..

Comment: Learn to use proper explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to select table2.ref_no, table2.payment, table1.start_date and
>   table1.name where table2.payment is null and where table2.ref_no equal
>   table1.ref_no sorted by table2.ref_no

Use `JOIN` instead of comma syntax and change the order of `table_name.column_name`:

```
SELECT Table2.ref_no, Table1.name, Table2.payment, table1.start_date, Table2.tel 
FROM Table1
JOIN Table2
  ON Table1.ref_no = Table2.ref_no 
WHERE Table2.payment IS NULL 
   OR Table2.payment = ' ' 
   -- explicit search for space maybe you want '' (empty string)
ORDER BY Table2.ref_no
```

---

For readability is good practice to add aliases:

```
SELECT t2.ref_no, t1.name, t2.payment, t1.start_date, t2.tel 
FROM Table1 AS t1
JOIN Table2 AS t2
  ON t1.ref_no = t2.ref_no 
WHERE t2.payment IS NULL 
   OR t2.payment = ' '
ORDER BY t2.ref_no
```

Comment: Thank you .. this is the most explanatory answer I've ever got .. and it works